# QScopedPointer with signals and slots

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qscopedpointer

as the tittle says, i could not find any relationship or how to pass them to signals and slots.

Anyone could give me a quick tutorial? or Introduction? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get an `QObject-derived class object` from the `QScopedPointer` by `QScopedPointer::data()` method and use it:

```
QScopedPointer<QThread> p(new QThread);
connect(p.data(), SIGNAL(finished()), SLOT(onThreadFinish()));
```

[QScopedPointer class reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscopedpointer.html)

Comment: well now i am getting this error code QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a Qwidget. I might know where the problem is. Related to that, can i create global QScoped Pointer?

Comment: @AlexanderBafka: You cannot create static/global QPixmap/QWidget instances, as they require a QApplication to be constructed before. That’s unrelated to QScopedPointers though and would also happen with a raw pointer.

Comment: Global instances should be created with `Q_GLOBAL_STATIC`: they are created in a thread-safe manner, and are instantiated on the first use - after `QApplication` is alive and well.